# Codeigniter 3 - Test database connection on the fly - Not using config/database.php file

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I'm creating a web installer for my app. In the installer, I'll allow the user to enter values for server, username, password and database name.

Now using this values, how would I verify if my app can establish connection with the database

> Note: I'm not making use of the `config/database.php` file. Instead, I'll make use of the posted data by the user and test the connection. If successful, will write those values to the `config/database.php`

My controller code is as follows:

```
$host = $this->input->post('dbserver');
$username = $this->input->post('dbusername');
$password = $this->input->post('dbpassword');
$name = $this->input->post('dbname');

if(<can connect with the database using the above>) // <---- This is what I'm looking for
{
   // write to the config/database.php file
}
```

Comment: What `dbdriver` are you going to use?

Comment: Only `mysqli`..so that will be hardcoded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I figured it out.

Using `TRUE` or `FALSE` as the second parameter to `$this->load->database()` was always returning an object and hence checking `if($this->load->database())` was futile as it would always evaluate to `TRUE` even with wrong credentials.

So I went ahead and did this:

```
@$this->load->database($config, FALSE, TRUE); // using @ to avoid warnings in case of wrong credentials
if(@$this->db->initialize()) // again use @ to avoid error messages
{
   // now this verifies it truly connected
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [codeigniter documentation](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/connecting.html) you can use manual connecting to your database doing the following :

```
$config['hostname'] = $this->input->post('dbserver');
$config['username'] = $this->input->post('dbusername');
$config['password'] = $this->input->post('dbpassword');
$config['database'] = $this->input->post('dbname');
$config['dbdriver'] = {driver_to_use};
$config['dbprefix'] = {prefix};
$config['pconnect'] = {bool};
$config['db_debug'] = {bool};
$config['cache_on'] = {bool};
$config['cachedir'] = {cachedir};
$config['char_set'] = {char_set};
$config['dbcollat'] = {dbcollat};

if($this->load->database($config, TRUE))
{
  // Write the db config file
}
```

Following the [loader class reference](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/loader.html#CI_Loader::database) :

> Returns : Loaded CI_DB instance or FALSE on failure if $return is set to TRUE, otherwise CI_Loader instance (method chaining)

Comment: I put wrong credentials and tried to test it. The return was `CI_DB_mysqli_driver` object and also splash a warning on the page with a message `Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`. So `TRUE` doesn't seem to be honored. I would like to return either `TRUE` or `FALSE`

Comment: If I keep the second parameter to `FALSE`, the return value is `CI_Loader Object`...so in both cases `if($this->load->database())` will always return true

Comment: If you want to remove the warning but still check errors, you can set `$config['db_debug']` to `FALSE` and use `$this->db->error()` to check if an error occured instead of setting `@` in front of every command. The `@` has other implication described [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php) and shouldn't be used in most case. What if credentials are right ones and a network failure occure ?

Comment: That's odd. I do have `$config['db_debug']` set to `FALSE` and yet I'm receiving errors. The whole idea is to either let the check return only `TRUE` or `FALSE` and that's where it's failing